# Is there an advantage to use bound variables running Oracle single record update/insert?

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, oracle12c, devart

I am being pestered by Oracle admin telling that Oracle can optimize better requests if I use bound variables instead of inline. The code is C# and using Devart Oracle provider, Oracle12c+. I understand that it can have an impact if you run a select - statistics cached and next similar command would do better.. But single row insert/update? I am not convinced.

Anyone can give an informed answer?

Example:

```
update x set a = 0 where id = 100

vs 

update x set a = :a where id = :id
```

EDIT: the not-bound values are numeric only so the SQL injection is out of the scope of the question

Comment: I'm tempted to remove the c# tag from this post, seeing that the core of the question is about Oracle - it doesn't matter which language generates and sends the query. Thoughts?

Comment: Yes there is. You avoid SQL injection attacks. It's not just about optimization. The optimization benefit has to do with how many times the query has to be compiled into an execution plan. It doesn't matter how many rows are affected or returned. If you perform the same update 1000 times, avoiding 1000 recompilations will improve performance a lot. If the update is as cheap as you assume, *compilation* becomes a significant part of the overall cost

Comment: In short, the Oracle admin is right. You should listen to him and not just about *this* query.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The categorical answers prompted me to do a benchmark. It mimics exact prod server conditions.

Results on 30000 iterations (**difference is 6.5%**):

```
Inline vars: 00:01:09.7444764
Bound  vars: 00:01:05.4454827
```

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var LEN = 30000;
    var cmd = new OracleCommand();
    var sql = "update some_table set progress={0} where id=100";
    var rnd = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);

    //

    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();

    for (int i = 0; i < LEN; i++)
    {
        using(var cnn = new OracleConnection("xxx"))
        {
            sql = string.Format(sql, rnd.Next());
            cmd.CommandText = sql;
            cmd.Connection = cnn;

            cnn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    sw.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine("Inline vars: {0}", sw.Elapsed);

    //

    sw.Restart();

    sql = "update tm_fnet set progress=:p where id=:i";

    for (int i = 0; i < LEN; i++)
    {
        using (var cnn = new OracleConnection("xxx"))
        {
            cmd.CommandText = sql;
            cmd.Connection = cnn;
                        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("i", 100);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p", rnd.Next());

            cnn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    sw.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine("Bound vars: {0}", sw.Elapsed);

    //

    Console.ReadKey(false);
}
```

**Conclusion** - its not that important unless you have to care for SQL injections (*but that's irrelevant in my case*).

Comment: I don't think you're measuring the right thing here.  There is probably only one second of real database work being done here - why does your application take a minute?  (Is the application creating a new connection for each row, and sending data one-row-at-a-time?)

Comment: In addition, this looks like a serial test. I would imagine that your application would have users accessing the database concurrently. That is where there are big gains to be had. Here is a video that my group produce a while ago on this topic... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EBdZ-RE2HFs

Answer (score 2):

If you build queries via string concatenation from user input, you are highly vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. The DB admin wisely never wants to have to make [this call](https://xkcd.com/327/). It does not even mater what kind of operation you do - SQL injections can basically run random SQL code.

Now the exact alternate Method varries by your Programming langauge. In C#, you use [Parametized Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters). Not only are those SQL injection proof, it also offers some type-checking and should be faster. And personally I even find it more readable too. No need to make that maze of quotation marks.

However as you mentioned Bound variables, you might be using [Prepared Statements](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) instead. I will be honest: I rarely used them. They just seem way more complicated then it is worth. But if that is the only non-concatenation way your Libraries and Langauge support, that is the way you have to go.

Note that there is still a slim case where you *can* use concatenation. And that is if the string is not read from disk, the network or user input. I recently had a case, where depending on user input a IN clause had to be appended. And it was a differnt one (values and lenght), depending on the input. And I was using prepared statements, wich does not deal with it that well. However as the string to append was picked/generated 100% from scratch in a switch/case statement (wich was given the user input), there was no danger. At best random user input could hit the default case.

Comment: @BoppityBop Your edit did not provide anything new. Your example still is one of building queries via string Concatenation vs Parametized queries/Prepared Statements.

Comment: sorry - I didn't press "publish" see now.. sql injection is not the concern here.

Comment: @BoppityBop If the variables are numeric, even more reason to use Bound Variables/Parametized queries. If you try to concat them into strings, they are first turned into strings. And then parsed back by the SQL Server. You are adding load equivalent to a ToString()/Parse() while also increasing the total amount of data send to the server (strings quickly get bigger then integer values).

Answer (score 0):

There are **huge** performance advantages to using bind variables with simple `UPDATE` and `INSERT` statements.

First, there's the direct performance improvement from not having to parse so many unique statements.  A small `UPDATE` may seem like a simple thing at first, but there's a lot happening behind the scene.  Each unique statement must be parsed - Oracle has to check the syntax and security of each statement.  With bind variables, that work only happens once.  The simple test below shows an `UPDATE` running over 10 times faster with bind variables.

```
-- Create simple table with one record.
create table x(id number, a number);
insert into x values(100, 0);
commit;


-- 10,000 concatenated UPDATES - 5 seconds.
begin
    for i in 1 .. 10000 loop
        execute immediate 'update x set a = '||i||' where id = 100';
    end loop;
end;
/


-- 10,000 bind variable UPDATES - 0.3 seconds.
-- (Execute immediate is used here keep this test similar to above.)
begin
    for i in 1 .. 10000 loop
        execute immediate 'update x set a = :i where id = 100' using i;
    end loop;
end;
/
```

In addition, using bind variables may allow you to use batching and improve the performance by another 10x.

Using bind variables means there will be only one SQL_ID, which makes performance tuning and tracking for the DBA *much* easier.  With a single SQL_ID, there are many plan management options available, in case there is a bad execution plan.

Finally, creating a huge number of unique statements will fill up the shared pool (a memory structure used to contain execution plan information).  A huge number of statements might push other statements out of the pool, indirectly causing other performance problems.

Comment: whats `shared pool`? is it Oracle feature?

Comment: @BoppityBop Yes, the shared pool is an Oracle specific feature.  But every database probably has a cache for recently used SQL statements.